# Приложение "стробоскоп" работает некорректно

Tags: java, android

Имеется скомпилированный без ошибок код включающий и выключающий вспышку, но по задумке вспышка должна моргать, а не гореть. Чего делать она, никак не желает, бьюсь уже 4ый день. Может кто то сталкивался с подобным?

Скорее всего проблема где то здесь, но где и какая конкретно мне никак не понять

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean state) {
 if (state) {

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mCamera != null) {
                while (Switcher.isActivated()) {
                    String mode = mParams.getFlashMode();
                    if (mode.equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
                        mode = Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH;
                    else
                        mode = Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF;

                    mParams.setFlashMode(mode);
                    mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

Полное содержание MainActivity
    package a1.strobe;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton btnSwitch;

private Camera camera;
private boolean isFlashOn;
private boolean hasFlash;
Parameters params;
MediaPlayer mp;
ImageButton Switcher;
private Camera mCamera;
private Parameters mParams;
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton btn, boolean state) {
    if (state) {

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mCamera != null) {
                    while (Switcher.isActivated()) {
                        String mode = mParams.getFlashMode();
                        if (mode.equals(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF))
                            mode = Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH;
                        else
                            mode = Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF;

                        mParams.setFlashMode(mode);
                        mCamera.setParameters(mParams);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(500L);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Кнопка включения фонарика
    btnSwitch = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSwitch);

    //1:
    hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

    if (!hasFlash) {
        //2
        //3:
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .create();
        alert.setTitle("Ошибка");
        alert.setMessage("Ваше устройство не поддерживает работу с вспышкой!");
        alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //4:
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
        return;
    }

    getCamera();

    //5:
    toggleButtonImage();


    //6:
    btnSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isFlashOn) {
                //7:
                turnOffFlash();
            } else {
                //8:
                turnOnFlash();
            }
        }
    });
}


//9:
private void getCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
            params = camera.getParameters();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("Ошибка! : ", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


//Включаем вспышку
private void turnOnFlash() {
    if (!isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        //Проигрываем звук
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.startPreview();
        isFlashOn = true;

        //Меняем изображение кнопки при переключении:
        toggleButtonImage();
    }

}


//Включаем вспышку
private void turnOffFlash() {
    if (isFlashOn) {
        if (camera == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        //Проигрываем звук
        playSound();

        params = camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        camera.setParameters(params);
        camera.stopPreview();
        isFlashOn = false;

        //Меняем изображение кнопки при переключении:
        toggleButtonImage();
    }
}


//11
private void playSound(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
    }else{
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
    }
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }
    });
    mp.start();
}

/*
 12
*/
private void toggleButtonImage(){
    if(isFlashOn){
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.turn_on);
    }else{
        btnSwitch.setImageResource(R.drawable.turn_off);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //13:
    turnOffFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //14:
    if(hasFlash)
        turnOnFlash();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //15:
    getCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    //16:
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: onCheckedChanged - это у вас слушатель такой?

Comment: У Вас метод `onCheckedChanged` не задействован. Уберите у него параметры и вызывайте в `turnOnFlash` вместо кода включения вспышки (её включит сам метод)