# Стробоскоп на API21+

Tags: android, камера

Делаю стробоскоп на API 21 и выше. Стробоскоп нормально работает, но при отключении я получаю такую ошибку:

```
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service 
com.project.project.domain.service.Service has leaked IntentReceiver 
android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$1@261b1d that was originally registered 
here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
```

Моя реализация строба:

```
class StrobeRunner(var cameraManager: CameraManager, var on: Boolean, var id: String) : Runnable {
    var isOnOff = false

    fun stop(){
        on = false
        run()
    }

    override fun run() {
        while (on) {
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(id, true)
            Thread.sleep(500.toLong())
            cameraManager.setTorchMode(id, false)
            Thread.sleep(500.toLong())
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, как и кого отписывать в unregisterReceiver()?

Или возможно кто знает где посмотреть реализацию стробоскопа для для Api 21+?

Пробовал вот так: [Приложение "стробоскоп" работает некорректно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774355/238266)
и отсюда: https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/01/android-torch-app-with-stroboscopic.html и иные варианты для предыдущего апи. Не знаю почему, но если пробуешь включать вспышку по такому принципу в другом потоке, она не включается, а в mainThread без проблем.

**UPD:** Кто может подсказать чем чревато игнорирование вот этой ошибки? android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.project.project.domain.service.Service has leaked IntentReceiver android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager$1@29ea4a6 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Comment: Единственный способ решения найденный мною, это запускать стробоскоп из activity и тут же его выключать, но это не удобно для меня.

Comment: Так это, тут всё просто. У вас где-то добавляется подписка на события, т.е. выполняется код registerReceiver. При завершении приложения вы должны отписаться от этих событий, иначе события будут приходить туда, где уже и нет ничего, чревато красными ошибками в логкате.

Comment: Проблема в том что я сам нигде не подписываюсь, CameraManager подписывается, и если в Activity она он умеет отписываться, то в Service нет.